# Visual Studio Code: How to split the editor vertically

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, a while ago, when I used menu *View* → *Split Editor*, it would split vertically. (One file on the left and one file on the right.)

I updated Visual Studio Code and when when I do menu *View* → *Split Editor*, it always splits horizontally. (One file on the top and one file on the bottom.)

How can I split vertically?

Comment: Just open several files, then grab the tab of a file and drag it around the VS Code window - where you see the greyed out area is where the file will end up, you can split as many times both horizontally and vertically as you have screenspace.

Answer (score 514, accepted):

## Change editor split layout from horizontal to vertical

### In 1.20

- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> **PC** (Windows, Linux)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> **Mac**

### Pre-1.20

- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> **PC** (Windows, Linux)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> **Mac**

### In 1.25

- You can split editor into `Grid` layout. Check `View`=>`Editor Layout`
- It is nicely presented in [Release notes v1.25: VS Code grid editor layout](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_grid-editor-layout)

### In 1.58.2 **

** Someone update this with the lowest version where this became true.

- The menu entry with the shortcut given above is `View`=>`Editor Layout`=>`Flip Layout`
- The [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) entry is labeled "Toggle Vertical/Horizontal Editor Layout"
- The [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) entry is

  ```
  {
    "key": "alt+cmd+0",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleEditorGroupLayout"
  }
  ```

Comment: BTW, it is in `View` menu.
Look at `Toggle Editor Group Layout` just below `Split Editor`.

Comment: Note that this is NOT a method of having both horizontally and vertically split windows; VSC does one, or the other, but can't do both at the same time.

Comment: And for a unix based OS? I tried in ubuntu with no luck.

Comment: @gabodev77 Check in menu `View->Toggle Editor Group Layout`

Comment: `Alt+Shift+1` works for Linux Mint (which is Ubuntu based).

Comment: How to undo 'splitting view'?

Comment: @v-andrew Actually I usually open several different files per side so I may have to drag file by file from right to left, e.g., it takes time. I am looking for some way to do that all at once.

Comment: Very nice feature to split horizontal (for long file) and vertical (for wide file). After setting what split, I wish they can make it intuitive like other Windows app including VS itself, in which I was positioning my cursor to the upper right corner hoping to see a spliter....

Comment: Seems to have changed to `Cmd+Option+0` on v1.20 OS X

Comment: Note that this shortcut is relevant only _after_ the editors are already split. So you first need to do `Alt+Shift+1` and then `Alt+Shift+0` would toggle between vertical and horizontal split back and forth.

Comment: @DanielGriscom in version 1.27.2 you can combine vertical/horizontal editor layout, having any combination of multiple columns in each of multiple rows.

Comment: Wondering why can it do the Word or VS way? Give us a splitter thumb in the top right, we can drag and open, lot more intuitive than config this and that.

Comment: And to switch between them, use `Ctrl+1`, or `2` or `3` (`⌘` in mac).

Comment: why would they change this so often..

Comment: Checking new commits at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/463630e70436308da191b917656571c7afb78797/docs/getstarted/userinterface.md#side-by-side-editing should always provide the correct way to invoke this.

Answer (score 213):

If you're looking for a way to change this through the GUI, at least in the current version 1.10.1 if you hover over the `OPEN EDITORS` group in the `EXPLORER` pane a button appears that toggles the editor group layout between horizontal and vertical.

[image: Visual Studio Code - toggle editor group layout button]

Comment: Question... when I have a file open and I go to split the screen the same file I have open gets added to the new panel. Is there a way to just have it split without the same file or no file at all?

Comment: @TikaL13 Searching through the settings I don't see any customizations for Split Editor mode.  It doesn't allow a pane with no open tabs (it reverts to a single pane when the last tab it closed), so it's got to open _something_ when the new pane is created and it defaults to another view of the current file.  You can drag tabs between panes or open another file (the file will open as a new tab in whichever pane is active) and then close the initial tab of the second pane.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping it would function very similar to Sublime. I think I saw somewhere that this feature or fix would probably be included in the next release?

Comment: Although, I don't know how to change the "default" but for later [releases](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14909#issuecomment-393870565) I should hold onto `alt` when clicking on the `split editor` to toggle between the vertical and horizontal.

Comment: My workaround was to set `workbench.editor.closeEmptyGroups: false` (as suggested below) and then just routinely close the "same file" at once and then open empty tab or the file I wanted to open there.

Comment: @TikaL13 As of 2024, you can create a split panel with no editors open. With a single editor group present, if you press ctrl+2, it will show the second panel without any files. If you press ctrl+3 after ctrl+2, it will show one more panel.

Answer (score 55):

To split vertically:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> **Mac**

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> **linux**

command: `workbench.action.splitEditor`

To split orthogonal (ie. horizontally in this case):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> **Mac**

command: `workbench.action.splitEditorOrthogonal`

Comment: Is there any shortcut to "unsplit"?

Comment: Currently using `⌘`+`w`, though it needs to be done for each file.

Comment: `⌘` + `w` works if you want to close one of them.

`⌃` + `⌘` + `→` or `←`  works if you want to just move it

Comment: Thank you, these keys worked for me, using vscode v1.47.3. The top answer on here wasn't working, assuming keys changed with newer versions

Answer (score 21):

### Method 1

[image]

### Method2

*View -> Command palette -> type 'split'*

[image]

### Method3

[image]

### Method4

[image]

### Tip

Add a Keyboard Shortcut for split Editor

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Press `CMD + SHIFT + P` (MAC) and search for `Toggle Editor Group`

Comment: For some reason the key combo of ALT + Shift + 1 isn't working for me. This works though. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In version `1.23.1`, it is `Ctrl+Shift+P` and `Split Editor`
This will divide the screens vertically and you can move through them using `Ctrl+K+LeftArrow`

[image: Screenshot of the Split Editor]

Answer (score 8):

By default, editor groups are laid out in vertical columns (e.g. when you split an editor to open it to the side). You can easily arrange editor groups in any layout you like, both vertically and horizontally:

To support flexible layouts, you can create empty editor groups. By default, closing the last editor of an editor group will also close the group itself, but you can change this behavior with the new setting `workbench.editor.closeEmptyGroups: false:`

[image]

There are a predefined set of editor layouts in the new `View > Editor Layout menu:`

[image]

Editors that open to the side (for example by clicking the editor toolbar Split Editor action) will by default open to the right hand side of the active editor. If you prefer to open editors below the active one, configure the new setting `workbench.editor.openSideBySideDirection: down.`

There are many keyboard commands for adjusting the editor layout with the keyboard alone, but if you prefer to use the mouse, drag and drop is a fast way to split the editor into any direction:

[image]

Keyboard shortcuts#
Here are some handy keyboard shortcuts to quickly navigate between editors and editor groups.

If you'd like to modify the default keyboard shortcuts, see Key Bindings for details.

```
⌥⌘→ go to the right editor.
⌥⌘← go to the left editor.
⌃Tab open the next editor in the editor group MRU list.
⌃⇧Tab open the previous editor in the editor group MRU list.
⌘1 go to the leftmost editor group.
⌘2 go to the center editor group.
⌘3 go to the rightmost editor group.
unassigned go to the previous editor group.
unassigned go to the next editor group.
⌘W close the active editor.
⌘K W close all editors in the editor group.
⌘K ⌘W close all editors.
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply in windows

ctrl + @ (the button 2 in the upper horizontal row of numbers in keyboard)

Answer (score 5):

Use *Move editor into Next Group* shortcut:

Mac: `^` + `⌘` + `Right/Left arrow`

If you want to change shortcut:

1. Open `Command Pallette` (macOS keyboard shortcut: `⌘` + `Shift` + `p`)
2. Select *Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts*
3. Search *View: Move editor into Next Group*

Answer (score 4):

The key bindings has been changed with version 1.20:

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> for Linux.

Presumably the same works for Windows also and <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>OPT</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> for Mac.

Answer (score 4):

- Right-click on the tab that you want to split it into another screen.
- Then choose whether you want to split it (up-down | right-left).

I find this is the quickest way, and You can split it to as many screens as you want.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to configure the VSCode settings to make the default behavior the way you want:

Split Editor (to a new editor group)

```
"workbench.editor.openSideBySideDirection": "right" // left/right (default)
"workbench.editor.openSideBySideDirection": "down"  // up/down
```

Split Editor in Group (does not create new editor group)

```
"workbench.editor.splitInGroupLayout": "horizontal" // left/right (default)
"workbench.editor.splitInGroupLayout": "vertical"   // up/down
```

Answer (score 3):

I just found a simple solution. You can drag an opened file and move towards the four sides of the Editor, it will show a highlighted area that you can drop to. It will split the view automatically, either horizontally, vertically, or even into three rows.

VSCode v1.30.2

Update: you can also drag a file from the Explorer to split the Editor in the same way above.

Answer (score 2):

To change the editor in Landscape and Vertical mode, follow the steps below.

1. For example, open two files that you have in your left or right side bar, depending on where you are placed. By default it is always on the left.
2. Now that you have both windows open, you have to use the key combination for **PC (Alt + Shift + 1)** for (Windows and Linux Operating Systems) or for **MAC (Cmd + Option + 1)**, as commented here v-andrew.