# Visual Studio Code Now Horizontally splits the window

Tags: vim, split, visual-studio-code

I have been using Microsoft Visual Studio Code to write my Python code for awhile and have generally been pleased with it.  But sometimes it does 'strange' things.  Like now,  I tried to open the current window in split mode.  It did, but instead of splitting it vertically as it always does, it did so horizontally.  Any idea on how to open it split vertically as before?

I am using the most current version of the VSCode and have the VIM plugin installed which works great.

Comment: Definite dupe - the accepted answer (by the OP) just points to the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies for hasty posting.  Upon doing more google search, I came across the following post in StackOverflow:
[how to toogle horizontal or vertical split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709351/vscode-how-to-split-editor-vertically)

This answers my question fully.  You may delete this or mark it as duplicate.