# How to change VScode split editor button from horizontal to vertical

Tags: visual-studio-code

Updated Vscode and the new `split editor button`, now splits editors horizontally. It used to be vertically. How do I set it back to the way it once was — vertically?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSCode: How to Split Editor Vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709351/vscode-how-to-split-editor-vertically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question: how to change the split screen button:

`cmd + opt + 0` mac

`ctrl + alt + 0` linux/win

Also there is a screenshot

when you see the response from @Bacon part of the way down on this thread [vs-code-how-to-split-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709351/vscode-how-to-split-editor-vertically)

Answer (score 1):

use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to toggle between horizontal and vertical splitting.

Note: Don't use 1 from number pad.

You also can achieve this with **view --> Toggle editor group layout**

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> **PC** (Windows, Linux)

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> **Mac**

Source: [VSCode: How to Split Editor Vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709351/vscode-how-to-split-editor-vertically)