# How do I open the same file side by side in a single Visual Studio Code session?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Say I'm reading file *xyz.py*. And I want to see both `func_x` and `class_y` at the same time, so that I don't have to keep on scrolling up and down to go back and forth.

How would I open file *xyz.py* side-by-side so that I can read both at the same time?

**Note**: This is different from the question *[Visual Studio Code: How to split the editor vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709351/vscode-how-to-split-editor-vertically)*, as it doesn't explain how to have the same window side by side.

Comment: found this for atom https://atom.io/packages/scroll-sync

Answer (score 134, accepted):

In the top right of your screen there should be a split editor button that looks like this: [image: split editor button]

That should do the trick.

The default keyboard shortcut (on windows) is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

Comment: sublime can open the same file in multiple tabs, how to do it in vs code?

Comment: @datdinhquoc Looks like that hasn't been implemented yet. Heres the github issue discussion regarding it: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41289

Comment: Default keyboard shortcut on MacOS is `Command` + ``\``

Answer (score 22):

## In Command Palette

(<kbd>Ctrl or ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)

Type `split e` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

(Select *View: Split Editor*)

## In sidebar

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left-click</kbd> the file

## In editor

Click the Split Editor button ([image: Split Editor]) in the upper right corner.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above worked for me

but  ⌘ + \ worked.

Comment: This is not I wanted but it maybe the best alternative,, I miss sublime,,