# How to duplicate selected editor in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like the same functionality as for tabs in browser. I didn't find any related extension in marketplace and any command from vs code pallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing that exactly mirrors the "Duplicate" functionality from (for example) Chrome, but you can open the same file side-by-side (or top-and-bottom) in two editors using the "Split" functionality. Right-click on the tab and choose one of the "split" options (each will open the second copy in a different place), or refer to the answer linked below for screenshots and several alternative ways to invoke the "split" command.

[How do I open the same file side by side in a single Visual Studio Code session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674275/how-do-i-open-the-same-file-side-by-side-in-a-single-visual-studio-code-session)

Comment: That's very sadly.