# How to split terminal in VSCode for two different Python scripts running at the same time

Tags: visual-studio-code

In trying to run a server.py and client.py file using VSCode's integrated terminal, I want the terminals to be vertically split.
However, running the files (`Ctrl+F5`) creates new terminals.

Note that the terminals that open are '*Python Debug Consoles*'

Comment: probably a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709351/vscode-how-to-split-editor-vertically#:~:text=1%20if%20you%20hover%20over,layout%20between%20horizontal%20and%20vertical.&text=The%20key%20bindings%20has%20been,%2B%20OPT%20%2B%200%20for%20Mac.)

Comment: what's wrong with having a new terminal? You'll need one to run a second python file anyways

Answer (score 2):

You can split the terminal in `vscode` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>

You can also acheive this by pressing the `Split Terminal` button between the `New Terminal` button and the `Kill Terminal` button.[image]